# How to run installed ubuntu inside of installed windows

Tags: linux, windows

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04/Windows 8.1. I want to play couple rounds of some game in between tasks which I develop in Ubuntu. Games are running on windows, so each time I need to reboot, but it consumes too many operations.

Is there any way to load installed Ubuntu while in Windows? Any ideas or directions?

Thanks!

I already had some discussion on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028781/how-to-run-installed-ubuntu-inside-of-installed-windows/25029048) which considered as offtopic (hi Cap)

Comment: Install Ubuntu in a virtual machine on Windows (or the other way around). Or move your development environment to Windows (e.g. perhaps MinGW is appropriate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a handful of options I can think of:

1. Another computer.  Obviously, this might not be convenient or cost effective, but with two computers, you have both Windows and Ubuntu running at full power.  You can always VNC/RDP/Synergy/VPS/whatever to the other machine to control it.
2. Virtual Machine.  Most likely run Ubuntu in a VM on Windows, giving Windows the most power for your games.
3. [AndLinux](http://www.andlinux.org/). It looks like its still in development...  andLinux is a complete Ubuntu Linux system running seamlessly in Windows 2000 based systems (2000, XP, 2003, Vista, 7; 32-bit versions only).  The need for Windows to be 32 bit might be an issue for you.
4. [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).  Depending on which Windows games you are playing, they might be Wine compatible and you can play them directly in Ubuntu.  Wine (originally an acronym for "Wine Is Not an Emulator") is a compatibility layer capable of running Windows applications on several POSIX-compliant operating systems, such as Linux, Mac OSX, & BSD. Instead of simulating internal Windows logic like a virtual machine or emulator, Wine translates Windows API calls into POSIX calls on-the-fly, eliminating the performance and memory penalties of other methods and allowing you to cleanly integrate Windows applications into your desktop.
5. [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/). Cygwin is a large collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows.  Depending on your needs, Cygwin might offer the development tools you need or give you the ability to download the source and compile them.
6. [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).  MinGW provides a complete Open Source programming tool set which is suitable for the development of native MS-Windows applications, and which do not depend on any 3rd-party C-Runtime DLLs.  Again, depending on your needs, this may work for you.
7. Obviously, there are many cross platform languages, compilers, IDEs.  Depending on your needs, you can find what you need for any platform.
8. There are numerous online development [environments](http://www.google.com/search?q=online+compilers&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS513US513&oq=online+compilers&aqs=chrome..69i57.3185j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=online+development+environment) and [compilers](http://www.google.com/search?q=online%20compilers&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS513US513&oq=online%20compilers&aqs=chrome..69i57.3185j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).
9. [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/).  Steam has many Linux games, although personally Im not impressed with the list...  But, there are native Linux games.  Also, you can stream a Steam game from another PC to another Steam client.  This of course, requires another computer (option 1).
10. I have no option 10, just wanted to round off the list.

Comment: Thanks, it is not solving my problem in the way I wanted, but at least I learned something new :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommenced you use a virtual machine e.g VMware so you can run 2 operating systems at once, you can choose all of the ram and things you put in to it and its exactly like a actual operating system.